# Teradata : Using Column reference in the Interval Parameter

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a problem with a query, I want to add an interval to a date, and the interval parameter is a value of a column in my table.

My table is like this

```
DATE_       | STEP
2019-10-01   10
2019-11-01   30
```

This query fails :

```
SELECT 
,BEGIN(EXPD) AS DH_STEP
,DATE_
FROM MY_TABLE
EXPAND ON PERIOD(CAST( DATE_ || ' 00:00:00' AS TIMESTAMP(0)), CAST(DATE_|| ' 00:00:00' AS TIMESTAMP(0)) + INTERVAL '1' DAY)
EXPD BY INTERVAL STEP MINUTE;
```

Actually, the query succeeds if I replace STEP by '10' for example.

Thank you.

Comment: Try `BY step * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BY INTERVAL` must be a hard-coded value. You might code a workaround to create an interval for every minute first and then filter based on the step:

```
SELECT 
   Begin(EXPD) AS DH_STEP,
   DATE_
FROM
 (
   SELECT EXPD, step
     ,DATE_
   FROM MY_TABLE
   EXPAND ON PERIOD(Cast( DATE_ AS TIMESTAMP(0)), Cast(DATE_ +1 AS TIMESTAMP(0))) AS EXPD 
   -- if step is always a multiple of 10 you can reduce the number of rows using `10`minute
   BY INTERVAL '1' MINUTE
 ) AS dt
WHERE Cast((dh_step - Cast( DATE_ AS TIMESTAMP(0)) Minute(4)) AS INT) MOD step = 0
```

Comment: When you say `BY INTERVAL must be a hard-coded value`, is that specific to when used with expand?  Gordon's suggestion works with date/time math.

Comment: Yep, it's the `BY INTERVAL` option of the `EXPAND` only.

Comment: It works fine! Thank you! the step is always a multiple of 10